# Auto reboot of a Luks Container

Tags: disk-encryption, ubuntu-server, luks, key-file

I have tried autobooting a luks container on Ubuntu Server (20.04) with a keyfile and a keyscript.  My '/etc/crypttab' entry for both options are as follows.

Keyfile:

```
dm_crypt-0 /dev/sda3 /root/keyfile luks
```

Keyscript:

```
dm_crypt-0 /dev/sda3 none luks,keyscript=/root/lukopen.sh
```

With the keyfile crypttab line it is ignored on reboot and I have to get in manually with the passkey.  With the keyscript crypttab line I get a fatal error (nothing coming back from the script) and the OS hangs.

The keyfile and script are in the root directory.  The keyscript returns the contents of the keyfile.  The last character in the data returned from the script is not a newline character.  I am using 'echo -n' in the script.

I understand that this may be bad for security on the one level.  My hardware is an embedded solution and I only need to secure the drive in the event that it is powered up by another system.  It's too easy to brute force a non encrypted drive and redo the sudo password so I would rather there be some encryption to thwart this.

I have been struggling with this for a couple of days and any pointers to getting either of these approaches running would be much appreciated.

My current thinking is that 'none' in the keyscript line may need something in it, and bash may not be up and running at the time of the passkey request.  The problem in the keyfile example may be an order thing in the luks keyfile.  Either way I don't know what I don't know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if its a typo or an error in your post - you say the file is in your root directory (this means /) while you point to root users home directory (/root).  Questions - what is the correspinding line in your /etc/fstab file?  (you need both an fstab and crypttab entry)  It may be that to need to rebuild your initrd or similar to get this executed early in the boot process depending on where its mounted

Comment: Unrelatedly, can you tell us about your hardware? If it has some kind of tpm you may be able to tie that in to LUKS to brovide better protection for your use case.

Comment: Of course '/root' is in the encrypted area.  I need to place the files in '/' not '/root'.  So many articles on line discuss mounting an encrypted drive rather than working with an encrypted OS - I missed that.  Also,  I am relatively new to linux.  It's a fascinating OS but I am finding the learning curve very steep.  I will try that and get back with the results.  Also, linking encryption to a tpm is an angle I hadn't thought of.  I will check the bios of the embedded system to see if I can see if hardware is fitted.  Great input - thank you.

Comment: Sadly there are no hardware security chips on the system.  A nice idea though.  I am hoping that by not using the UUID ident for the hard drive and by having a serious number of log files in the / directory, of which only one (or maybe, sneakily, a combination of two separate files) can be used as the keyfile.

Comment: Your idea of hiding the key in log files and not using ident are trivially thwarted, so are likely not worth pursuing.   The problem you are trying to solve is a hard one, with no single good solution.   It might be adequate to use another storage mechanism, require someone manually log in to the system to supply the key on reboot or have the system reach out across the Internet to get its key.

Comment: @davidgo I tried the following crypttab entry `dm_crypt-0 /dev/sda3 /keyfile luks`and it didn't pick up the keyfile.  So I then did an `update-initramfs -u`and I got a warning message saying 'skipping root target dm_crypt-0: uses a key file'.

Comment: @davidgo, from what I have read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164403/unlock-luks-encrypted-debian-root-with-key-file-on-boot-partition) trying a boot at this point may be foolhardy.

Comment: As an experienced Linux system administrator who recently went a few rounds with Luks - and not even encrypted root (I had other very tricky requirements), you are likely right about yourvsystem not being in a stable config.  I'd seriously reconsider copying off the data, then starting again without LUKS on root, and setting aside a partition you mount after boot and store your sensitive data on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135552/discussion-between-david-poundall-and-davidgo).

Answer (score 1):

Two excellent posts from 2015 by Pavel Kogan [here](https://www.pavelkogan.com/2014/05/23/luks-full-disk-encryption/) regarding Arch Linux luks and [here](https://www.pavelkogan.com/2015/01/25/linux-mint-encryption/#fnref:script) regarding a Debian twist that he worked out, along with the nudge from @davidgo provided me with my luks encrypted autoboot solution.  This is how it works for me.

On a new Ubuntu server 20.04, built with the standard luks options create a keyfile to use as a key then add it to the next luks key slot using cryptsetup.

```
dd bs=512 count=4 if=/dev/urandom of=/crypto_keyfile.bin
cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda3 /crypto_keyfile.bin
```

nano into the /etc/crypttab file and using your own encrypted drive logical partition name and primary partition drive enter

```
dm_crypt-0 /dev/sda3 /crypto_keyfile.bin luks,keyscript=/bin/cat
```

This fixes the second thing I was doing wrong.  I didn't appreciate that the third entry in the crypttab line (normally seen as 'none') is in fact an argument of the executable (in this case 'cat') called by the keyscript equate.

The third thing I would not have considered unless I had read Pavel's document was that in order for the physical keyfile to be seen there needed to be a hook for initramfs to use.  I copied Pavel's simple script called crypto_keyfile

```
#!/bin/sh
cp /crypto_keyfile.bin "${DESTDIR}"
```

into /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/ and made it executable.

```
chmod +x /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/crypto_keyfile
```

The last thing I did was update the initramfs with

```
update-initramfs -u
```

Once I got back to the command line I rebooted linux and this time it loaded without needing the passphrase.

When I took the drive out of the embedded hardware and put it into a separate system and try to mount it, it asked for a passphrase to mount the disk, which is the functionality I was aiming for.